# valgrind leak error after deletion of all dynamic memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have tried to learn CPP pointer as well as to free all the memory about which I have used `valgrind`. But unfortunately I am getting leak error and I don't know where I am making the mistake. Also not so much idea about finding error as a human-readable way from valgrind. Any guidance to find the leak is highly appreciable.

**compiler:** `g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~16.04) 7.5.0`

**related info regarding snippet**

- `smart pointer` is not used intentionally
- it is a minimal example code. So, some portion might seem to be unnecessary.

`file.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

void algo_fun(unsigned int*  ip_ptr_array_,
              unsigned int   ip_size_,
              unsigned int** op_ptr_array_,
              unsigned int*  op_size_)
{
    *(op_size_) = ip_size_ + 2;

    // following approach is good as it allocate dynamic memory
    unsigned int* local = new unsigned int[*(op_size_)];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i< *(op_size_); i++)
    {
        local[i]=i+1*3;
    }

    *op_ptr_array_ = &local[0];
    local[3] = 87;
}

int main()
{
    // input array's contetnt
    unsigned int ip_size = 10;
    unsigned int* ip_ptr_array = new unsigned int[ip_size];

    // output data
    unsigned int op_size;
    unsigned int* op_ptr_array;

    // filling input array
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ip_size; i++)
    {
        ip_ptr_array[i] = i+2*2;
    }

    // function calling to get output data
    algo_fun(ip_ptr_array,
             ip_size,
             &op_ptr_array,
             &op_size);

    delete [] ip_ptr_array;
    delete [] op_ptr_array;

    return 0;
}
```

Working version will be found [**here**](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef2556575a3afe8b).

**command used to test:** `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./file`

`Leak Summary from valgrind`

```
==23138== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23138==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23138==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23138==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23138==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==23138==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23138== 
==23138== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==23138== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why are you manually using   `new` an `delete` at all? That's what containers and smart pointers are for in c++.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, valgrid prints "All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible".

Comment: `algo_fun(ip_ptr_array, ip_size,&op_ptr_array,&op_size);` -- There is no need for the last parameter to be a pointer.  It should just be a plain `int`.  If you look at the `algo_fun` function, it does absolutely nothing to suggest that it should be a pointer -- a `nullptr` check is not done in that function, for example.  It looks like you went overboard with pointerizing everything in your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As I understand, `ip_` means _input parameter_ and `op_` means _output parameter_. The `algo_fun()` stores the number of elements of the output array into the location pointed to by the `op_size_` pointer, see: `*(op_size_) = ip_size_ + 2;` Thus, it needs to be a pointer. As for pointerizing everything, I think the author is just learning/exercising their knowledge about pointers in C++. Otherwise, there'd be no need to use pointers anywhere at all, just `std::vector`s and references. I think this code is just a proof of concept. For example, `ip_ptr_array_` parameter is unused.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ intentionally `smart pointer` is avoided.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. can you share the compiler info or exact code that one you have tried? I know maybe you have just taken my code and then found the expected `leak free answer` from `valgrind` but I have no idea what is going on in my system.

Comment: I tried several gcc versions from 9 to 11, your exact code with no changes. You have a rather old system with an old compiler. Maybe that's what's going on. Try valgrind with --track-origins=yes, maybe you will see which block is not freed.

Comment: `--track-origins=yes` has nothing to do with leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr Please check that you are using a recent Valgrind.

With a combination of Valgrind and gdb you should be able to see what is going on.

I get the following (FreeBSD 12.2, g++ 10.3.0, Valgrind built from git HEAD, [OS and compiler version are not relevant]). I'm using the `--trace-malloc=yes` option to see all the mallloc/free calls. Don't do that on a large application.

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --trace-malloc=yes ./test

--61886-- malloc(72704) = 0x5800040
--61886-- calloc(1984,1) = 0x5811C80
--61886-- calloc(104,1) = 0x5812480
--61886-- calloc(224,1) = 0x5812530
--61886-- calloc(80,1) = 0x5812650
--61886-- calloc(520,1) = 0x58126E0
--61886-- calloc(88,1) = 0x5812930
--61886-- _Znam(40) = 0x58129D0
--61886-- _Znam(48) = 0x5812A40
--61886-- _ZdaPv(0x58129D0)
--61886-- _ZdaPv(0x5812A40)
--61886-- free(0x5800040)
==61886== 
==61886== HEAP SUMMARY:
==61886==     in use at exit: 3,000 bytes in 6 blocks
==61886==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 3 frees, 75,792 bytes allocated
```

_Znam is the mangled version of array new and _ZdaPv the mangled version of array delete from your code. The other calls to malloc/calloc/free come from libc/libstc++. You will probably see different traces on Linux or with libc++.

You could use `--show-reachable=yes` to get information on the reachable memory.

If I now run under gdb.

```
$ gdb ./test
(gdb) b malloc
(gdb) b malloc
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, malloc (nbytes=96) at /usr/src/libexec/rtld-elf/rtld.c:5877
```

This is a call to malloc in the link loader, ld.so. I then executed several more 'r's until

```
Breakpoint 1, __je_malloc_initialized () at jemalloc_jemalloc.c:208
```

Here the link loader has loaded libstdc++.so and global malloc has been replaced by jemalloc.

Getting the callstack

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __je_malloc_initialized () at jemalloc_jemalloc.c:208
#1  imalloc (sopts=<optimized out>, dopts=<optimized out>) at jemalloc_jemalloc.c:1990
#2  __malloc (size=72704) at jemalloc_jemalloc.c:2042
#3  0x00000008006eb6f4 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/gcc10/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x000000080060e2fd in objlist_call_init (list=<optimized out>, lockstate=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/libexec/rtld-elf/rtld.c:2820
#5  0x000000080060d03d in _rtld (sp=0x7fffffffe408, exit_proc=0x7fffffffe3d0, objp=0x7fffffffe3d8) at /usr/src/libexec/rtld-elf/rtld.c:811
#6  0x000000080060a8c9 in rtld_start () at /usr/src/libexec/rtld-elf/amd64/rtld_start.S:39
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Note the same allocation size on line `#2`.

I'm not going to dig into what this memory is for, something part of the C++ runtime.

libstdc++ (and libc) deliberately do not free this memory (presumably this is either difficult or just not worth it). In order to filter out these allocations, Valgrind uses a special function to ask libstc++/libc to free this memory.

The option in this case is

```
    --run-cxx-freeres=no|yes  free up libstdc++ memory at exit on Linux
```

(strictly speaking, not just Linux).

Looking at the Valgrind release notes

```
Release 3.12.0 (20 October 2016)
...
* New option --run-cxx-freeres=<yes|no> can be used to change whether
  __gnu_cxx::__freeres() cleanup function is called or not. Default is
  'yes'.
```

So I presume that you are using version 3.11 or earlier.

Finally, if I use clang++/libc++ there is no runtime allocation (and also no freeres function).

Comment: yes, it was  a version issue